# How to put a border around the text in a button?

Tags: html, css

I would like to have a coloured border around the text of a button.

My button is like this:

```
<input id="btnexit" class="exitbutton" type="button" value="Exit" name="btnExit"></input>
```

I already add in CSS the style of the border of the button, but I need to add also a coloured border around the text `Exit`.

Is it possible to do that in CSS? How could I do otherwise?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of how you want?

Comment: Hi Nathan, I've just subscribed and with no reputation I can't upload images. Anyway, what I needed is what shown in the example provided by Razz in his answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put a span inside the button, that way you have two elements to style.

html:

```
<button>
    <span>click me!</span>
</button>
```

and the css:

```
button{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: #eee;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
button span{
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

[Example!](http://jsfiddle.net/yX4UD/)

Comment: you can not put `span ` in `input` tag

Comment: Yeah, that's true. Finally I managed to replace my input tag with a button and styled the span, as described here by Razz.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Razz. Thanks to all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

**try this :**

```
<button type="button">
     <span style="border:1px solid #FF0000;">Button</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

LIke this

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XdS8C/2/)**

```
 .exitbutton {

padding:10px;
background-color:white;
  cursor:pointer;
}
input{
    border:1px solid blue;
}
```